# MySQL Server Scaleing with AWS issues

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, aws-ec2

MySql server doesn't seem to be scale up correctly when scaling up my AWS instance. Its almost like MySql is cacheing the instance sizes.

This happens after a scale down the AWS instance and then when we scale back up the the AWS instance, the MySQL server seems to remain in the smaller state even though the AWS instance has doubled in RAM and CPU

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you expect MySQL to scale up with the instance size?

Comment: Yes, thats how I expected it to work, or get some advice on how I can achieve the MySQL to scale up automatically. 

or the setting I need to change manually, post scale up if its not possible automatically 

thanks

T

Comment: @Tom           Additional information request, please. 
AWS instance type?  Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.  Welcome to serverfault.

Comment: How much RAM in each case?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL doesn't adjust its settings according to the resources available on the server. For example, by default, it allocates a mere 128 MB for its InnoDB pool. It is expected that you read [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/) and adjust settings according to your needs.

Alternatively, instead of running MySQL on EC2 you can run a managed [AWS RDS MySQL](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/mysql/) instance, they have some settings already adjusted to the instance size.

Comment: Hi @AlexD We are using a managed AWS RDS MySQL instance, yet when we scale done and back up the MySQL seems to remain in the smaller size. 

What settings would you recommend looking at so this MySQL scales up correctly?